# Deserialize json consting of possibly many different classes

Tags: python

I have a python package consisting of (many) modules where each module contains a dataclass and new modules and classes are added regularly. All of these classes inherit from a root class. My goal is to make it as easy as possible to add another module and class to this package. For example, I want to avoid that one has to modify other modules in the project when adding another class.

Now, I have one object of one of these classes and want to serialize and deserialize it. My question is, what is the most maintainable solution for this process?

I thought about the following.

For encoding, I would add an "encode" function to the root class and override it in the child classes.

For decoding, I am unsure what the best approach is. I also would add an "decode" function to the root class and override it in the child classes. The question is how do I find the correct class for the given encoding?

My idea here is to create a module for a decoder. The module imports all of the classes and the decoder has a long elif chain to find the correct class of the given object. However, this sounds like spaghetti and one always has to import new classes to this module and add them to the decoder.

What is an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: Add some field in your json file with information about what class you have stored. Maybe a version number to be future proof. Then a reader can call to the proper decoder depending on that

Comment: How are your classes structured currently - Is it safe to assume they are all [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)?

Comment: You can also maintain some kind of registry, mainly a dict to map a unique name for each class (used in the JSON data) to a class object or a decoder function specific to this class. New classes can add themselves to this registry.

Comment: http://jsonpickle.github.io/

Comment: @rv.kvetch Yes, they are dataclasses.

Comment: Design questions where there are multiple good answers possible are generally a better fit for [programmers.se] rather than Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is better suited for questions about specific, narrow problems. See also [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: Agreed, this question is potentially more opinion-based. However, I have put forth an answer on what I "personally" consider an elegant approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to building custom encoder and decoder helper functions from scratch, I'd suggest leveraging an existing JSON serialization library that can make this process much easier.

Since you mentioned that your model classes are currently [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), I would suggest using the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library that should work with existing dataclasses, with minimal changes needed.

In case you need data validation, I would suggest checking out a library like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) that similarly performs really well. In fact, they are both really fast in terms of deserialization / serialization, however it's likely worth doing your own tests to confirm as well.

Here is a simple example using a nested dataclass model that should work for Python 3.7+ with the included `__future__` import:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union


@dataclass
class A:
    my_data: B
    my_str: str = 'hello World!'
    # note: I'm working on supporting the `int | bool | None` syntax
    # for Python 3.7+; currently, that only works in 3.10
    my_field: Union[int, bool, None] = None


@dataclass
class B:
    another_field: Union[str, int]
```

Code for testing:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from dataclass_wizard import fromdict, asdict

    a = fromdict(A, {'myData': {'AnotherField': '21'}})
    assert isinstance(a, A)

    print(a)
    # A(my_data=B(another_field='21'), my_str='hello World!', my_field=None)

    print(asdict(a))
    # {'myData': {'anotherField': '21'}, 'myStr': 'hello World!', 'myField': None}
```